# How to instant filter an array of objects based on user's input?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

This was supposed to be easy, but it honestly got me scratching my head for some reason.
I am trying to filter an array of objects based on the user's input.

```
[{ name: Stan, age: 20, height: 190 },
{ name: Pan, age: 30, height: 180 },
{ name: Dan, age: 28, height: 185 },
{ name: San, age: 20, height: 170 }]
```

If a user Types 'S' for example, they would get 'Stan' and 'San'.
If they type 'St' it narrows down to 'Stan', so on, and then display the results as they are happening.

I have tried to filter the array based on the first letter, push it to a second array and filter the second based on the second input, but it wasnt working as expected. So at this point I am stuck at this.

```js
filterCat() {
    this.cate.filter(cat => {
        if (cat.name.startsWith(this.searchTerm.toUpperCase())) {
            this.tempSearchStore.push(cat);
            console.log('cats', cat);
        }
        // this will show all the cats based on the first letter.
    });
}
```

this is my html:

```html
<ion-searchbar animated [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" debounce="1000" 
  (ionChange)="filterCat()" mode="ios">
</ion-searchbar>
```

Comment: show your html.

Comment: i edited the question, and displayed the html.

Comment: Look at here - http://coderjony.com/blogs/creating-a-pipe-to-filter-the-items-in-the-list-using-angular-7/

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
this.cats = [{name:'Stan', age:20, height:190},
{name:'Pan', age:30, height:180},
{name:'Dan', age:28, height:185},
{name:'San', age:20, height:170}]


function filterCat(searchTerm: string) {
 return this.cats.filter(cat => cat.name.toUpperCase().startsWith(searchTerm.toUpperCase()));
}

console.log('Filter S');
console.log(filterCat('S'));

console.log('Filter Sa');
console.log(filterCat('Sa'));

this.whereverList = filterCat('Sa')
```

and:

```
<div *ngFor="let cat in whereverList ">{{cat.name}}</div>
```

You just have to pass your search term to the function

Comment: Hi, so i am using  [(ngModel)]="searchTerm", isn't this enough? I am already using it in the function, so why do i need to pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Yes you can also use `this.searcTerm` instead of the parameter. But using the parameter makes it easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

**startsWith()** method is case sensitive and you are uppercasing each letter of the searchTerm and that's where your condition gets failed.
You need to do something like this:

```
if (cat.name.startsWith(this.searchTerm.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
    this.searchTerm.slice(1))) {

    this.tempSearchStore.push(cat);
    console.log('cats', cat);
}
```

Have a look at this

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8ovg6?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: yes thank you, this is partially correct, but it still incomplete. I need to filter as i am typing.
So i type 'S' it shows all the cats with S, if i type the next letter it has to filter it down to 'S and the next letter'. you know what i mean?

Comment: @Don-Ricardo understood what you said. Check the Stackblitz link again! I updated it

Comment: unfortunatley it is not working at all. It is logging so many results, and not displaying anything

Comment: @Don-Ricardo I believe I've made the logic clearer, AGAIN. Although, I've added one for loop and nothing else. I hope this might be what you were looking for. :D